# application crash on startup when I add more than 3 other plugins in flutter

Tags: android, plugins, flutter, dependencies

I am beginner in flutter, when I add more than 3 other plugins in dependencies of pubspec.yaml my application crash after run it, but if I comment one of the plugins application work very well, please help

this is my code

```
dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+7
  firebase_database: ^3.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Try without provide specific version or try to update flutter.

Comment: Have you try with the recent dependencies: `shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1`? I've tried adding the dependency to my project but it didn't crash when run.

Comment: can you please show the stacktrace?

Comment: I do all of this but not working yet

Comment: I solve my issue with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454656/flutter-android-app-crashes-upon-startup-if-i-include-a-certain-package?rq=1