# Unfortunately, flutter_app has stopped

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm a beginner to flutter. I use vscode for development. I also debug using my physical android device instead of an emulator. I built a simple flutter application. Executed using flutter run. After building, white screen popped in my phone and soon followed by the dialogue "Unfortunately, quiz_app has stopped.", where quiz_app is the project name. I have a Ryzen-5 Machine. Here is the output of `$ flutter -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (5 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\haari\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
```

This is the console log when I do `$ flutter run` :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G531F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        20.0s
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterActivity( 8697): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 8697): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 8697): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
E/DartVM  ( 8697): version=2.7.0 (Fri Dec 6 16:26:51 2019 +0100) on "android_arm"
E/DartVM  ( 8697): thread=8697, isolate=vm-isolate(0xab699540)
E/DartVM  ( 8697):   pc 0x54cfcfcd fp 0xffcb8e58 libflutter.so+0x1321fcd
E/DartVM  ( 8697): -- End of DumpStackTrace
```

Here is the main.dart code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(QuizApp());

class QuizApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('JIT Quiz App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('What is your favourite subject?'),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('DBMS'), onPressed: null),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('DAA'), onPressed: null),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('CA'), onPressed: null),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('PQT'), onPressed: null),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to avoid debugging using an emulator as much as possible.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show some code.

Comment: @ArshShaikh I have added the source code as per your request.

Comment: Please add stacktrace

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I tried using `adb logcat` and got a ton of response from my cmd, are you sure I did it in the correct way or is there any some other way to do that.

Comment: Try flutter clean command and then run again, did you tried !!!!

Comment: First off I'd like to know how does your app run without using MaterialApp() widget? Coz when I tried to do it, it just throws error.

Comment: @AR did that, the problem still persists

Comment: @ArshShaikh yea it's My Bad. I have updated the code now but still the problem persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297571/dart-flutter-application-crashes-on-startup check this, there are many solutions there, hope it solves your issue.

Comment: @ArshShaikh I checked it out, I don't think it's related to my problem, anyhow I checked my AndroidManifest.xml and gradlew.build, the package domain is in correct format

Answer (score 0):

You should return the MaterialApp() first.
MaterialApp is the starting point of your apps. It tells flutter that you will be using material components in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, a very blunt mistake from my end. But that hasn't yet solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your android project from Android Studio and then run the application in your device.
You will then able to see the proper error message in your console due to which your app was crashing.

[image: This is the location to your main android project]

Comment: I am seeing the same error message in android studio

Comment: Did you open the "app folder inside your flutter project's android directory"  or the flutter project with android studio?

Comment: I opened the flutter project, what should i do after opening the app folder? BTW I am not seeing the release folder inside my app folder

Comment: Just open the app folder and run your app. Then check the console for clear error message. The release folder is not important

Comment: I am unable to run my app by just opening the app folder, as in the play button is greyed out

Comment: Try Android Studio-> File -> Sync project with gradle files. or try to clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

Step 01:
Add internet permission in `android/app/src/AndroidManifest.xml` just like this

> ```
>    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>         <application
> ```

Step 02: In `android/app/build.gradle` add

```
   >  buildTypes {
    >         release {
    >             // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
    >             // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
    >             signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    >             minifyEnabled false
    >             shrinkResources false
    >             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    >         }
    >     }
```

**It worked for me.**

Comment: I don't have access to that project anymore to check this answer out and I am not into flutter development anymore as well. If anyone else finds this solution working kindly let me know so that I can mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks in advance.