# I am getting error while running my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, runtime-error, building

When I am starting debugging I get this error :

> Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A5000 in debug mode...
> lib\main.dart:1 E/AndroidRuntime(11211): in writeCrashedAppName,
> pkgName :com.new.package.azabazar E/AndroidRuntime(11211): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(11211): Process:
> com.new.package.azabazar, PID: 11211 E/AndroidRuntime(11211):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.new.package.azabazar/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.example.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.new.package.azabazar-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.new.package.azabazar-1/lib/x86,
> /data/app/com.new.package.azabazar-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib,
> /vendor/lib, /data/downloads, /data/priv-downloads]]
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2570)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6138)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MainActivity" on path:
> DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.new.package.azabazar-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.new.package.azabazar-1/lib/x86,
> /data/app/com.new.package.azabazar-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib,
> /vendor/lib, /data/downloads, /data/priv-downloads]]
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1108)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2560)
> E/AndroidRuntime(11211):  ... 9 more

Comment: looks issue from pkg namemaybe it will help you =>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297571/dart-flutter-application-crashes-on-startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delete

```
android/
ios/
build/
web/
```

Those folders.

Then run `flutter create .`

Then change package name by running `flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.company.azabazar`

this might solve your prob :)

Comment: Caution: Better copy the suggested folders before deleting. They might have changes that you will need when recreating.